# html canvas - issue with moving image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am learning html canvas and below is my html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function moveImage(x) { 
    var context = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
    context.drawImage(img, x, 259);
}
img.src = "flower.jpg";
}

function startDrawing() {   
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(50, 300);
    context.lineTo(950, 300);
    context.stroke();
    var x=50;   
    setInterval(function() {
        x = x+20;
        moveImage(x);
    }, 1000);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="startDrawing()">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="1000">
</body>
</html>
```

**Please find the below output from this code:**[image]

How can I remove the traces of 'older frames' (of the flower), as you could see lots of flowers while it is moving from left to right in the screen shot ? Please help the code changes required.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you aren't clearing the canvas before drawing on it again. You can clear it using [`clearRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect).

```
setInterval(function() {
  // Clear the canvas
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  x += 20;
  moveImage(x);
}, 1000);
```

Keep in mind that this will clear the *entire* canvas. If you're rendering anything else, you'll want to redraw it after the clear.

Comment: any other alternatives without clearing entire canvas ?

Comment: @VA31 You can clear parts of the canvas. For example `context.clearRect(x, 259, 100, 100)` (adjust for the width and height of your image) will just erase where the image was last drawn. But it will erase part of that line you appear to have drawn as well. Basically, you have to erase rectangles on the canvas then redraw those areas.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is something wrong about my answer?

Comment: Thanks Mike, I got your point and accepted the answer. Not sure who down voted.

Answer (score -1):

You need to re-render the frame. Here's some code from an incomplete game I wrote:

```
var main = function () {
  var now   = Date.now(),
      delta = now - then;

  update(delta / 1000);
  render();

  then = now;

  // Request to do this again ASAP
  requestAnimationFrame(main);
};
```

[GitHub repo code](https://github.com/antibland/super-badger/blob/master/game.js)

My render function contains the `context.drawImg()` work (getting properly re-rendered), and that's similar to your `moveImage` function.

**Edit:** A little explanation. The image traces are previous renderings of the your image at each updated position. Without the frame itself being reset, each move of the image is preserved on the screen, giving the appearance of a trail of images.

Comment: The provides a basic heartbeat but doesn't explain why the image is leaving "traces".

Comment: Wow, that was a quick down vote. I edited my answer and offered a some explanation.

Comment: I was answering at the same time so I naturally saw your answer pretty quickly. Of course I'm going to downvote an answer which doesn't actually answer the question. If you edited your answer to directly address the problem instead of tossing in something as an afterthought, I would undo my downvote.